# Razor - editable grid - what approach?

Tags: razor, grid, edit

I am very much wondering and don't know yet what to decide to use.
So I want to have grid and to edit its row's data.

I am working with MVC3 Razor, i know for these posibilities:
- jqGrid Razor
- knockout grid Razor - i don't know how to make it editable grid? Is it possible at all, or is this just for displaying data.
- web grid , Razor

I don't like to use Telerik controls! 
Would you pls advice me what is the best approach to make editable grid and what if i don't need editable grid? Why to use one or other of the ways?
And all that in Razor page.

Answer (score 1):

[ShieldUI's grid](http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/grid-editing/inline-editing) also supports a lot of editing modes, scenarios and sending the updates locally or to any remote endpoint.

A good example to start can be found here:

http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid definitely does support editing, you can see some examples at http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html or read the documentation at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start

Comment: Thank you Vlad, yes. What do you think about knockout.js? I can see that it can also does some editing, but i start to think that maybe jqGrid is better way to go? Also Webgrid seems to be used only for visualisation?

Comment: @Diana I'm not quite sure you should look at jqGrid and Knockout as being mutually exclusive; see http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html for more info on it. I haven't personally tried it, but it looks pretty good. Maybe someone can comment on that, or you could post a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Use The Following Code For ***Editing*** and Same as **Add**, **Delete**.

For ***View***,

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<CustomerOrderDetails>()
                       .Name("gvCustomerOrderDetails")
                       .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.ItemID))
                       .Columns(column =>
                       {
                           column.Bound(i => i.ItemID).Hidden(true);
                           column.Bound(i => i.SalesSequenceNumber).Hidden(true);
                           column.Bound(i => i.ItemSequence).Hidden(true);
                           column.Bound(i => i.ItemName).Title("Item Name").ReadOnly();
                           column.Bound(i => i.Quantity).Title("Order Quantity").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "gridTextAlignRight" });
                           column.Bound(i => i.ItemUnitPrice).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "gridTextAlignRight" }).ReadOnly();
                           column.Bound(i => i.ItemUnitPrice).Hidden(true);
                           column.Bound(i => i.TotalPrice).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "gridTextAlignRight" }).ReadOnly();
                           column.Command(command =>
                           {
                               command.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                           }).Width(80).Title("Commands");
                       })
                       .Selectable()
                       .DataBinding(dbBindings =>
                           {
                               dbBindings.Ajax().Select("__CustomerOrderDetailsGridBind", "CustomerInfo")
                                                .Update("__CustomerOrderDetailsUpdate", "CustomerInfo");
                           })
                       .ClientEvents(events =>
                        events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding")
                              .OnError("onError")
                       )
                       .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(300))

                 )
```

For ***Control*** Use the following Code,

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult __CustomerOrderDetailsUpdate(CustomerOrderDetails objCustomerOrderDetails)
    {
        SalesItem objSalesItem = new SalesItem();
        objSalesItem.SalesSequenceNumber = objCustomerOrderDetails.SalesSequenceNumber;
        objSalesItem.ItemSequence = Convert.ToByte(objCustomerOrderDetails.ItemSequence);
        objSalesItem.ItemID = objCustomerOrderDetails.ItemID;
        objSalesItem.Quantity = objCustomerOrderDetails.Quantity;
        objSalesItem.ItemUnitPrice = objCustomerOrderDetails.ItemUnitPrice;
        objSalesItem.TotalPrice = objCustomerOrderDetails.ItemUnitPrice * objCustomerOrderDetails.Quantity;
        objSalesItem.SalesDate = DateTime.Now;
        objSalesItem.EntryBy = objLoginHelper.LogInID;
        objSalesItem.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;

        customerDal.UpdateSalesItem(objSalesItem);

        return View(new GridModel<CustomerOrderDetails>
        {
            Data = customerDal.CustomerOrderDetailsInfo(objCustomerOrderDetails.SalesSequenceNumber, Helper.Active)
        });
    }
```

you can also use your Model specific Class for ***Add***, ***Edit*** & ***Delete***. Here ***ReadOnly()*** is used for unedited column. If you need the column value in control then use same column without ***ReadOnly()*** and just ***Hidden***.

I think all are enjoy using this code.